# how to convert a text/plain to text/x.shellscript

Tags: linux, windows, shell, encoding, scripting

I am sending a .sh file created from a windows machine to a linux so that I could run it there. The problem is that I keep on getting an error called bad interpreter.But when I program the shell script in the linux machine it runs with no problems even though it has the same code with the one sent from the windows machine. After my ivestigation, I found out that the windows machine .sh script is a text/plain file(using file -bi) and the other one from the linux machine is a text/x.shellscript. Is there a way to convert the text/plain to a text/x.shellscript? thank you

this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

date
sudo apt-get update
```

I tried a solution by doing another .sh file in a linux box containing only

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then the windows machine only sent a file containing test commands like :

```
date
hostname
```

Then I append the file from the windows box to the linux one with

```
cat windows.sh >> linux.sh
```

It did not work if I run linux.sh. It says errors like:

```
./linuxh.sh: line 2 $'date\r':command not found
./linuxh.sh: line 2 $'hostname\r':command not found
```

However, if I open Linux.sh then save it again without doing anything. It works

Comment: I suspect the first line has the wrong path to your shell. How about showing us the script?

Comment: I said "Please show us the script", not "Where was the script made?"...

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry for that misunderstanding. I edited my post with the sript.

Comment: Please put 4 spaces at the start of each line of the script so it formats properly.

Comment: The first line should probably be "#!/bin/bash" or "#!/usr/bin/bash"

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for all the help. I still don quite know how to fully use this site.

Comment: If you type "which bash" on your Linux box it will tell you what to add after "#!" on the first line.

Comment: So there is a "/" missing. It should be "#!/bin/bash" not "#!bin/bash"

Comment: @MarkSetchell done typing "which bash" it said #!/bin/bash. I did it but still I got an error sayung bash: ./filename.sh /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok, we have solved one problem (wrong path) now we need to solve the second which is that there are <CR> at the end of the line (^M). You need to run "dos2unix yourscript"

Comment: Take @fedorqui's advice (but correct the typo): `dos2unix filename` on the linux machine, or use a text editor on windows that allows you to save a file with unix-style line endings.

Comment: @glennjackman can you give an example of a windows text editor that can do what you say?

Comment: Vim and Notepad++ come to mind.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, the dos2unix solution was a success. I hope you can still help us in other matters about windows to raspbian conversion and sending of files in the near future.

Answer (score 7):

I'm summarising below the steps you need to take so other users can see easily what needs doing:

Firstly, you need to check your script has the correct path to your interpreter after the "#!" in the very first line. This is should probably be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

and you can find which is correct by typing:

```
which bash
```

on your Linux box.

Secondly, you need to make sure that any Windows carriage returns (or "^M") at the ends of the lines are removed before expecting your Linux box to run the script. You can do this with:

```
dos2unix yourscript
```

Just for reference, you can easily see weird characters such as TABs or linefeeds or carriage returns in Linux by using:

```
cat -vet yourfile
```

or

```
sed -n l yourfile
```

Thirdly, you need to make sure your script is executable on Linux, using chmod like this:

```
chmod +x yourscript
```

Finally, when you have done all that, you need to either add the directory where the script is located to your PATH variable (and export it) or give the full path to your script like this if your script is in the current directory:

```
./yourscript
```

or like this if it is located somewhere else

```
/some/directory/some/where/yourscript
```