# Bash - :No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple bash script as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5000
```

When I try to execute it, I am getting a weird error

```
: No such file or directory
```

Note the **semicolon :**. All the usual stuff such as permissions are fine. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you try to execute the script? Also, is `bash`'s path really `/bin/bash`? check it with `which bash`.

Comment: Your script probably has funny characters.  Try saying `cat -vte scriptname`.

Comment: I am executing using `./test`. Output of `which bash` is `/usr/bin/bash`

Comment: @devnull I like to remember it as "cat -vet" because when your cat is broken you send it to the vet! :-)

Comment: So change the first line to #!/usr/bin/bash

Comment: @Mark Setchell every bash file I have ever seen starts #!/bin/bash  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2179809 or google

Comment: @camelccc Firstly, the OP may not be on Ubuntu - he didn't say either way. Secondly, if "which" says that bash is located in "/usr/bin/bash" - which it does - then "/usr/bin/bash" is the correct path to add after "#!"

Comment: I am on Fedora. cat -vet shows `#!/bin/bash^M$
sleep 5000^M$`

But I've tried opening the file, deleting everything and creating again. still same..

Comment: Aha! You have carriage returns. You need to run "dos2unix yourscript"

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314783/how-to-convert-a-text-plain-to-text-x-shellscript/21315569#21315569

Comment: Thanks mark, but I am not using windows so I wonder why i am getting those carriage returns..

Comment: Where did your script originate from? Has it been FTPed around? What editor are you using? Is your editor saving in Windows/DOS <CR> format?

Comment: I am on fedora, I used vi to create the file. No FTP etc..

Comment: You can create a script by typing "cat > script" and then typing in your script and hitting <Ctrl-D> when you are done without any editor.

Comment: @MarkSetchell dos2unix does fix it. Thanks. Still interested to find out how that happened

Comment: `:` is not a [semicolon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon), it's a [colon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please execute `dos2unix yourscript` to convert your file in linux formate